# Drupal language module?

Tags: drupal

Is there a module in Drupal that let's you select a language on the site and every piece of content changes in that translation, as long as you browse the site?

Answer (score 2):

Drupal has a few core modules that will assist creating multilingual sites, namely **Content Translation** and **Locale**.  You might also be interested in the [Internationalization module](http://drupal.org/project/i18n).  From the Internationalization project page:

> This is a collection of modules to extend Drupal core multilingual
>   capabilities and be able to build real life multilingual sites. Some
>   features:
>
> - Taxonomy translation (both, per language terms and translatable terms)
> - Multilingual variables
> - Multilingual blocks (control visibility per
>     language and translate title and content)
> - Language selection (when you
>     switch the site language you'll see only the content for that
>     language)
> - Requires the Variable module (Drupal 7)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the language for a bunch of nodes at once, install [Language Assignment](http://drupal.org/project/languageassign).

Then you can go to your content admin page and then set the language there.